# How to vertically half-fill a chevron/signal arrow with arrow shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to get a chevron/signal arrow half-filled like this:

[image: chevron arrow half-filled]

The normal solution to half-filling shapes doesn't apply here, because I also want the separation to be in the arrow shape. I also thought about putting two half-sized arrows right next to each other but then you would have to place the text manually, which is not very elegant (or maybe someone has an elegant solution to this?).

What I currently have is this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=signal,signal from=west,signal to=east,align=center,fill=lightgray,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,on chain,minimum height=5em},start chain=going right,node distance=2mm]
\path
    node{multiline\\ text\\ and\\ more}
    node{multiline\\ text}
    node{multiline\\ text}
    node{multiline\\ text\\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code uses another `signal` node inside a `path picture` option for the outer node. I couldn't make it work with `chain` so I propose `positioning`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
myarrow/.style={signal, signal from=west, signal to=east, minimum height=5em, minimum width=2cm},
innerarrow/.style={myarrow, fill=blue!70, anchor=east},
outerarrow/.style={myarrow, align=center, fill=lightgray, font=\footnotesize\sffamily, 
    path picture={\node[innerarrow, minimum width=1cm] at (path picture bounding box.east){};}},
node distance=2mm, 
]
    \node[outerarrow] (1) {multiline\\ text\\ and\\ more};
    \node[outerarrow, right=of 1] (2) {multiline\\ text};
    \node[outerarrow, right=of 2] (3) {multiline\\ text};
    \node[outerarrow, right=of 3] (4) {multiline\\ text\\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: automatic width**

Following code still uses a `path picture` but to fill the area computed with `calc` library. It's similar to what [pascal974 proposes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633390/1952) but inside node options instead of with two independent commands.

As I don't know how to refer to `thisnode`, node's name is defined as parameter to be used into `path picture` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes, positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
myarrow/.style={signal, signal from=west, signal to=east, minimum height=5em,
    align=center, fill=lightgray, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    name=#1, 
   path picture={\fill[blue!70] ($(#1.north west)!0.5!(#1.north east)$)--
        ($(#1.west)!.5!(#1.east)$)--($(#1.south west)!0.5!(#1.south east)$)
        --(#1.south east)--(#1.east)--(#1.north east)--cycle;}},
node distance=2mm, 
]
    \node[myarrow=1] {multiline\\ text\\ and\\ more};
    \node[myarrow=2, right=of 1, minimum width=5cm] {multiline\\ text};
    \node[myarrow=3, right=of 2, minimum width=6cm] {multiline\\ text};
    \node[myarrow=4, right=of 3, minimum width=4cm] {multiline\\ text\\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works but only for this certain size. You would have to manually adjust the blue part if the arrow gets longer or shorter. Could this be amended to automatically adjust the size to half of the gray arrow?

Comment: @SethosII I've updated the answer with an automatic mechanism

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes,calc,scopes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    chevron/.style= {%
            draw,
            shape=signal,
            signal from=west,
            signal to=east,
            align=center,
            font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
            minimum height=5em}
}
\newcommand{\chevron}[1]{%
    \node[name=s,chevron,on chain]{#1};
    \filldraw[lightgray,opacity=1]%
    (s.north west)--
    ($0.5*(s.north west) + 0.5*(s.north east)$)--
    ($0.5*(s.west) + 0.5*(s.east)$)--
    ($0.5*(s.south west) + 0.5*(s.south east)$)--
    (s.south west)--
    (s.west)--
    cycle;
    \filldraw[blue,opacity=1]%
    ($0.5*(s.north west) + 0.5*(s.north east)$)--
    (s.north east)--
    (s.east)--
    (s.south east)--
    ($0.5*(s.south west) + 0.5*(s.south east)$)--
    ($0.5*(s.west) + 0.5*(s.east)$)--
    cycle;
    \node[chevron]at(s){#1};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    { [start chain,node distance=2mm]
        \chevron{multiline\\ text\\ and\\ more}
        \chevron{multiline\\ text}
        \chevron{multiline\\ text\\ text};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. \node[name=s,chevron,on chain]{#1}; this instruction to name the node to draw 2 polygons.
2. \filldraw[lightgray,opacity=1]...
   to draw the left half polygon (if opacity < 1, the item 4 not necessary
3. \filldraw[blue,opacity=1]...
   to draw the right half polygon
   4
4. \node[chevron]at(s){#1}; it's the same node (s) of item 1 ; no chain (superimpose)

Sorry for my very bad english. I think the solution of Ignasi is better

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: @pascal974: Thanks, that works, but could you add some explanatory text on how you constuct the arrow, so it is easier for others to understand what it does?